# Mandar dos variables de php a una funcion con JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tengo el siguiente boton, en el cual quiero mandar el valor que tiene la variable $id (en este caso $id=28) mas el dato '1'.

```
<div class="btn-group pull-center">
    <a href="#" onclick="validar(<?php echo $id , 1 ?>);"><button type="button" class="btn bg-purple "><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button></a>
 </div>
```

Y lo mando mediante el siguiente Script

```
 function validar(id, status) {
  $.confirm({
    title: "Mensaje del sistema",
    content: "Esta acción validara el recibo de pago \n\n ¿Desea continuar?",
    buttons: {
      somethingElse: {
        text: "Aceptar",
        btnClass: "btn-purple",
        action: function () {
          var parametros = { action: "ajax", id: id, status: status };
          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "ajax/modificar/recibo.php",
            data: parametros,
            beforeSend: function (objeto) {
              $("#loader").html("<img src='./img/ajax-loader.gif'>");
            },
            success: function (data) {
              $("#resultados_ajax").html(data);
              $("#loader").html("");
              window.setTimeout(function () {
                $(".alert")
                  .fadeTo(500, 0)

                  .slideUp(500, function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                  });
              }, 5000);
              load(1);
            },
          });
        },
      },
      cancelar: function () {},
    },
  });
}
```

Al momento de cotejar que datos me esta enviando mediante el inspector de red de mi navegador me muestra que solo estoy enviando un dato en vez de dos.....
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se donde estoy fallando, si en el archivo donde mando a invocar la función o en el Script.....

Comment: Tu enlace con el onclick tiene un error en donde imprimes php
<a href="#" onclick="validar(<?php echo $id;?>,1);"><button type="button" class="btn bg-purple "><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button></a>

Comment: @GerardoMarroquin Gracias era eso :)

Comment: @GerardoMarroquin puedes colocar la respuesta para que la vea la comunidad